# Change a div to be full screen if screen changes to a small screen like a mobile device

Tags: html, css, fullscreen, viewport

Im really struggling to articulate what im trying to achieve, please bear with me on this..

I've got a small "widget" on the left and side of my page.
This work fine on bigger screens.

For example, the widget is say 300px wide in the style.

However, If i load the page on  a mobile or shrink the window, This becomes unfeasably small.
How do i get it to automatically change from 300px to full 100% width if a "smaller" viewspace is observed?

So say, i shrink my window , it would suddenly jump to be 100% wide rather than 300px? ( or similar)

Any ideas?

Sorry if I haven't explained it well enough. I've googled and nothing really sticks out that achieves what im doing.. maybe im not looking for the correct terms.. In a bit of a i dont know what i dont know to google it.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to say is "How can I make my website responsive?". You can do that with the [CSS Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp). Check the link and google for more informations.

To give you an idea, just try this:

```css
.my-class{
color: white;
background: black;
width: 300px;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .my-class {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="my-class">
    Some text!
<div/>
```

The break point here is at 600px, for large screens you have the width of the div is at 300px, for small screens you'll get the width taking 100%. (Try to resize the width of the current window while running the snippet to understand how it works).

edit: you can also use as the following style (the idea is in the `min-width`), if this is what you're looking for.

```
my-class{
  width: 300px;
  min-width: 100%; /* or 100vw depending on what you want */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently,you are using the CSS-Unit "**px**". If you want to have a size relative to the screen, the units **%**, **vw** and **vh** would be useful.

- **%** is relative to the parent element, which is probably the whole document, so you could work with that as a relative unit.
- **vh** represents the percentage of the viewports heigth, so you could use it for the heigth of your widget
- **vw** represents the percentage of the viewports width, so you could use it for the width of your widget

These were just some examples, if you want to learn more about the CSS Units, go to https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css_units.asp

I hope I could help you.

However, if you want to keep your px unit you can use the **media query**, as already mentioned by Il Saggio Vecchino. This allows you to have a different design at different devices.

Also take a look at https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: Thanks, Only used PX to just get my div to show. Ill probably use vh,vw eventually as that make smore sense.